# base64 syntax in python is not working

Tags: python, base64

this code works on the command line.

```
python -c 'import base64,sys; u,p=sys.argv[1:3]; print  base64.encodestring("%s\x00%s\x00%s" % (u,u,p))' user pass
```

output is 
dXNlcgB1c2VyAHBhc3M=

I am trying to get this to work in my script

```
test = base64.encodestring("{0}{0}{1}").format(acct_name,pw)
print test
```

output is
ezB9ezB9ezF9

anyone no what i am doing wrong ?
thank you.

Comment: You format the value returned by `encodestring`. `encodestring("{0}{0}{1}".format(acct_name,pw))` should work correctly.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the string passed on the commandline also has `\x00` between the substitution parameters...

Comment: Should this question be flagged as a typo, or should the title be changed to represent the actual problem? I lean towards the former.

Comment: VAULTAH = see SZYM's answer, as i think i have a formatting issue, and possibly an issue with single and double quotes...?

MGILSON = I am still trying to figure out the hex 00 and why it is needed. The original purpose of cmd was to test authentication of a TLS connection, so the hash is needed and works.
RETI43  = Yes i had a lot of trouble figuring out how to properly describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in parenthesis. Instead of:

```
test = base64.encodestring("{0}{0}{1}").format(acct_name,pw)
```

(which first encodes "{0}{0}{1}" in base64 and **then** tries to substitute variables using `format`),

you should have

```
test = base64.encodestring("{0}{0}{1}".format(acct_name,pw))
```

(which first substitutes variables using `format` and **then** encodes in base64).

Comment: Thank you SZYM, you got me a lot closer. I tested u=apple p=apple an get YXBwbGUAYXBwbGUAYXBwbGU= via command line. my script gives this YXBwbGVhcHBsZWFwcGxl   This is the new error i get.  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'appleapple' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SZYM i am all set. This is the code that gets it to work

```
test = base64.encodestring("{0}\x00{0}\x00{1}".format(acct_name,pw))
```

Turns out the hex \x00 is needed so program getting the hash knows where username stops and password begins.
-ALF